# How to render the table using DataTable with the following data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

```
var data = [
    {
        "Area": "Plant",
        "Equipment": "E-312A",
        "PermitNo": 4321.0,
        "PermitType": "Hot Work",
        "Section": "A"
    },
    {
        "Area": "pipe",
        "Equipment": "E-312A",
        "PermitNo": 231.0,
        "PermitType": "Hot Work",
        "Section": "B"
    },
    {
        "Area": "A",
        "Equipment": "P-100A",
        "PermitNo": 45.0,
        "PermitType": "Hot Work",
        "Section": "A"
    }
]
```

My desired output:  There should be table pagenation i.e.,page1 should contain data of data[0],
page2 contains data[1] and so on. The column values are only Property and Values.

```
 Property        value
=====================================
  Area           Plant
  Equipment      E-312A
  PermitNo       4321.0
  PermitType    Hot Work
  Section            A
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $(table).DataTable({
            bSort: false,
            aoColumns: [{ sWidth: "45%" }, { sWidth: "45%" }],
            "scrollY": "200px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "info": true,
            "paging": true
        });. Also I am generating table dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code for data table:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  <div id="div1"> 
  <table  cellspacing="0" width="100%"  id="mytable">
        <thead>
           <tr>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >

        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
  <script>
  var data = [
               {
                    "Area": "Plant",
                    "Equipment": "E-312A",
                    "PermitNo": 4321.0,
                    "PermitType": "Hot Work",
                    "Section": "A"
                },
                {
                    "Area": "pipe",
                    "Equipment": "E-312A",
                    "PermitNo": 231.0,
                    "PermitType": "Hot Work",
                    "Section": "B"
                },{
                    "Area": "A",
                    "Equipment": "P-100A",
                    "PermitNo": 45.0,
                    "PermitType": "Hot Work",
                    "Section": "A"
                }

]

$(document).ready( function () {


  var exampleRecord = data[0];
var keys = Object.keys(exampleRecord);


for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
if(i==0){
$("#mytable thead tr").append('<th>Property</th> <th>Value</th>');
}


for(var j=0; j<keys.length; j++)
{

var keyValue=keys[j];

    var tr="<tr>";
    var td1="<td>"+keyValue+"</td><td>"+data[i][keyValue]+"</td></tr>";


   $("#mytable").append(tr+td1); 
  } 


}


 var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  bSort: false,
  "scrollY": "200px",
  "scrollCollapse": true, 
    "info": true, 
    "paging": true,
    "pageLength": keys.length
 });

});


  </script>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}


div.container {
  min-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I dont want columns' Header to be keys. Please see my desired output where "Property" column should consist of keys and "Value" should consist of values

Comment: Hi @reciever, I have just updated my answer please try again.

Comment: Great!!...Thanks again @Pramod